# Diplaying the selected item from the drop down box and display them in a table format

Tags: angularjs

Hi Im trying to list the items selected from the drop-down box and display it in a table using angularjs.So here is the code,

https://plnkr.co/edit/8qCgB2flMGB89moppkz6?p=preview

abc.html

```
 Car Brand:
        <select name="carname" ng-model="userSelect" required>
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
             <span ng-show="valdate.carname.$error.required">Car name</span>
            <option ng-repeat="ManufactureBrand in a" ng-bind="ManufactureBrand" >
                {{ManufactureBrand}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/> Car Model:
        <select name="carmodel" ng-model="selectCar" required>
              <option value="">--Select--</option>
              <span ng-show="valdate.carmodel.$error.required">Car name</span>
              <option ng-repeat="CarName in b" ng-bind="CarName">
                {{CarName}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <br/>
            <input type="submit" ng-click="checkselection()" ng-disabled="valdate.carname.$invalid && valdate.carmodel.$invalid">
      <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Car Name</th>
                  <th>Car Model</th></tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td>{{list}}</td>
                <td>{{carlist}}</td>
                </tr>
     </table>
```

abc.js

```
 var app = angular.module('carService', []);

app.factory('Brandtest', function () {
    var brand = {};
    brand.sample = ['Bmw', 'Mercedes', 'Honda'];
    brand.car = ['Suv', 'Sedan', 'Cope'];

    {
        return brand;
    }
});

app.controller('selectDropdown', ['$scope', 'Brandtest', function ($scope, Brandtest) {
    $scope.a = Brandtest.sample;
    $scope.b = Brandtest.car;

    $scope.list=[];
    $scope.carlist=[];


    $scope.checkselection = function () {

        if ($scope.userSelect != "" && $scope.userSelect != undefined &&
            $scope.selectCar != "" && $scope.selectCar != undefined )
           {

           $scope.list.push($scope.userSelect);
           $scope.carlist.push($scope.selectCar);

        }
```

I have also attached image, how my final result is displayed.

here all the items in list once submitted are overlapping in the same row.
So, please help me to properly display the table and also on submitting the selected item from drop down I want them to be one below the other.

Comment: Sorry image file didnt upload properly.

Comment: can u make plunkr link with your code will be easy for all to resolve your issue

Comment: url is added @MBalajivaishnav

Comment: whats the actual problem, is the value are not showing in select ?.. b'coz your plunkr link has that error

Comment: I want to display the selected item from the dropdown box and put it in the table. @MBalajivaishnav

Comment: Thank you for helping out .... @MBalajivaishnav

Comment: not a prob @Rudhra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8uKhkeYTuq5AnGCqqlFH?p=preview)

The following are the code modified

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Car Name</th>
              <th>Car Model</th></tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="carz in list track by $index">
              <td>{{carz}}</td>
            <td>{{carlist[$index]}}</td>
            </tr>
 </table>
```